# Issue when loading a RichText Editor using .load()

Tags: jquery

I'm using a `.load()` call to open a url inside a div.  The url has a richhtml editor TinyMCE and it is initialized using the code below.  The problem is the richhtml editor loads just fine when the url is accessed directly, but whenever the url is used as a `.load(url)` then the richtext editor doesn't initialize at all.  I have the Mimetype set on the script so it should execute?  It looks like it is executing, there is just browser errors telling me 'Object Required' when i try.

I would like the Richtext editor to be initialized within the url so an extra initialization doesn't have to be done on the container's url using the `.load(url,init)` function.

Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

    <!--Rich Text Editor -->
    <textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({mode : "exact", elements : "desc", theme : "advanced",theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "code"});
</script>
```

Same result using .getScript();

```
<textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getScript('/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', function() {
tinyMCE.init({mode : "exact", elements : "desc", theme : "advanced",     
theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "code"});
                                                               });
                           });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Object Required" sounds like the `tiny_mce.js` file isn't being included and since you are trying to access a property of the `tinyMCE` object the parser is expecting an object to already be declared.

Try including the `tiny_mce.js` file into the document that is making the AJAX request and see if that solves the issue.

**UPDATE**

> Note: When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is however called with a selector expression appended to the
>   URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   which is why they are never executed.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: That seems to work, but why can't i load the .js file on the fly?  It must be in the <head>?

Comment: @ZeeTee If you are using a selector with your `.load()` URL (`.load('some_fild.html #content')`) then check my **updated** answer.

Comment: I have seen the Note, and i am just doing it like this $("#desc").load(url)  no expression.

Comment: @ZeeTee Well I guess `.load()` doesn't load external scripts. You can do that at the same time you call `.load()` with `$.getScript()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript. If you do use `$.getScipt()` use the callback function to run the `.load()` function so that `tiny_mce.js` will be parsed when the content is loaded.

Comment: I tried getScript() like the code above shows, and its still giving the same error.

Comment: @ZeeTee Like this? `$.getScript('/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', function () {$(<selector>).load(URL);});`. You want to call the `.load()` function after the `$.getScript()` function has called its callback